# Realizar modificacion en MongoDB en una fecha especifica

Tags: mongodb

Es posible actualizar un dato en mongoDB cada cierto tiempo, o en una fecha especifica?

Por ejemplo, que a un dato X, a partir de la fecha de creación pasado un mes se le agregue +1, o que cada 04 de mes se le descuente 2

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado / averiguado? En todo caso, eso no lo hace Mongo, debes programarlo, en el lenguaje que mejor te convenga. Saludos